# Display data from DB in Data table component

Tags: reactjs, mapping

I took a data table component. In it I want one row per object.

```
return (
           

         <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
  
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Adresse</th>
 
   
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    
      
      <td>{this.props.obj.nom}</td>
        <td>{this.props.obj.adresse}</td>
   
    
      
    </tr>
 
  </tbody>
</Table> 

        );
```

My obj is set with those two functions :

```
  getEntreprise = () => {
   axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/ent')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ liste: res.data });
                console.log(res.data);
                console.log('Data récupérée1 !');
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
  }

  dataTable() {
        return this.state.liste.map((data,i) => {
            return <DataTable obj={data}  key={i}/>;
        });
    }
```

I don't understand why it generates one component per item instead of a of Table row per item

Answer (score 0):

Here you map a new table for every mapping item inside array liste. Therefore you have to just map only table row tags inside a single table tag.

```
   getEntreprise = () => {
   axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/ent')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ liste: res.data });
                console.log(res.data);
                console.log('Data récupérée1 !');
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
  }

  dataTable() {
        return (
  <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
  
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Adresse</th>
 
   
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
{
this.state.liste.map((data,i) => (
            <DataTable obj={data}  key={i}/>;
        ));
}
    
  </tbody>
</Table> 
)}
```

And change DataTable component as follows

```
return (
    <tr>
      <td>{this.props.obj.nom}</td>
        <td>{this.props.obj.adresse}</td>
    </tr>
 
        );
```